# Laravel one to many relationship fetch data

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-8, one-to-many, relation

i make a one to many relationship in my project but when i want to fetch data it returns null response.

i have a user Model and Intership Model.

each user has one Intership and each Intership has many users. so , relationship is one to many .

i create this relation but i cant fetch data. i want to show intership information of a user.

MY USER MODEL :

```
<?php

 namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

  class User extends Authenticatable
 {
use HasFactory, Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'last_name',
    'email',
    'role',
    'phone',
    'user_code',
    'born_date',
    'national_code',
    'password',
];

protected $primaryKey = 'user_code';

protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password',
    'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];

public function intership()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Intership::class,'intership_code','intership_code');
   }
   }
```

MY INTERSHIP MODEL :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Intership extends Model
{
use HasFactory;

protected $table = 'interships';

protected $primaryKey = 'intership_code';

protected $fillable = [
    'teacher_code',
    'user_code',
    'school_code',
    'work_code',
    'intership_term_code',
    'intership_code',
    'class_code',
    'start',
    'end',
];

public function users()
{
    $this->hasMany(User::class,'user_code','user_code');
}
 }
```

MY CONTROLLER :

```
public function index()
{
    $user = User::where('user_code',32132)->first();
    $interships = $user->intership;
    return $interships;
}
```

Notes :

1- i dont have "id" field in my tables so instead of "id" i have user_code for users and intership_code for interships that are foreignkey

2- user with user_code => 32132 already exists.

3- i want to show a user intership information

Comment: Your relation keys are different for the 2 models. It needs to be the key in the users table and the key in the internships table. But the 2 relations need to have the same keys

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first things first, since you use your User model the relationship that you want to build is in the User model, the one in Internship model is irrelevant (at least for this question).

```
public function intership()
   {
    return $this->belongsTo(Intership::class,'user_code','user_code');
   }
```

Your foreign key in your `Internships` table that connects it with the `Users` table is the `user_code` which links to the `user_code` of the user in Users table.